# how to make column editable in table column with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Is it possible to make a tablecolumn editable when using angularjs? I have this table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr class="header">
        <th>id</th>
        <th>files</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <tr>
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.fileNames)}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I have a $scope.fileNames which is an array containing filenames per person for example:

```
["Koala.jpg","Tulips.jpg","Tulips.jpg","Hydrangeas.jpg","Lighthouse.jpg","Chrysanthemum.jpg"]
```

I would like to make this 2nd column editable for the user so he can change/delete the files how can I accomplish this?

Comment: if you are using gridOptions you can use:enableCellEdit: true. see a demo here:http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ or http://plnkr.co/edit/KJmYbO?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use `contentEditable`

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr class="header">
        <th>id</th>
        <th>files</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <tr>
        <td contentEditable>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td contentEditable>{{person.fileNames)}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```